# How do I use Tess4j in my programs?

Tags: java, netbeans, tesseract, tess4j, netbeans-8.1

I am undertaking a project using OCR in Java and have come across Tess4j. I am using netbeans on a mac and there doesn't seem to be any beginner information available. Do I actually need to have Tesseract installed to use Tess4j? If so, when I distribute my software will my users have to install Tesseract first? I have followed the instructions found here: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ but I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': Native library (darwin/libtesseract.dylib) not found in resource path ([file:/Users/unknown1/Desktop/Tess4J/lib/jai_imageio.jar, file:/Users/unknown1/Desktop/Tess4J/lib/jna.jar, file:/Users/unknown1/Desktop/Tess4J/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar, file:/Users/unknown1/Desktop/Tess4J/build/classes/, file:/Users/unknown1/NetBeansProjects/TesseractExample/build/classes/])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:78)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:40)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:360)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:273)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:205)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:189)
    at tesseractexample.TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:16)
/Users/unknown1/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Any ideas what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build and/or install Tesseract on Mac first. Once it's installed, `libtesseract.dylib` will be available for Tess4J to invoke.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to get it running from netbeans but when I compile and run as a standalone jar it doesn't work. If I find he libtesseract.dylib file can I include it in the same folder as the libraries and should it compile and work without the need to have Tesseract itself installed? I am hoping that my app could work cross platform and without the need for installs by the user. Is this realistically achievable?

Comment: I have seen an example for windows which includes the line: System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "32".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")) ? "lib/win32-x86" : "lib/win32-x86-64");
Am I correct in thinking that I would do the same but for libesseract.dylib? Would I include this in the libraries folder?

Comment: Yes, you use `jna.library.path` variable to help JNA locate and load the custom native libraries. If you chose to bundle them, they would need be placed in specific folders (see [JNA code](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Platform.java)).

That is an ambitious goal to get or compile all the required libraries and dependencies for so many different OSes and versions.

Answer (score 0):

you must be 64-bit OS so try to install 32 bit os JVM or if you must use 64-bit JVM, you'll need Tesseract and Leptonica 64-bit DLLs. Use the ones provided by https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64